# Phasors question please help?Very simple?

Tags: phasor

I have an exercise with phasors and it says the source voltage E=12 Volt. Does this mean it is 12∠0°? Or do I have to do some other conversion?

Comment: If this is for phasors there should be a sine or cosine input, not DC. Is that all they gave you?

Comment: By 12<0 I think you mean a sinusoid waveform having 12 volts peak voltage and 0 degrees phase, right? But that's not the same as 12Vrms, root-mean-square voltage is lower than peak voltage (sine amplitude).

Comment: Typically, it does mean 12<0.

Answer (score 1):

A phasor notation is generally specific for AC signals, and it is a representation which gives us the equivalent Euler notation, I mean it transforms a complex number to its magnitude and phase angle. So if you have an AC signal you can get the real signal value of a complex number and so get the magnitude and phase. In the case of a DC wave, if your circuit is in DC, you can use it by putting a zero phase for that if you want to treat a transient response for example.